# Get numbers from a txt file in the url using async await fetch

Tags: javascript, html, async-await, fetch-api

I want a simple javscript command that does this:
1. user press the button.
2. with 'onclick="pressed"' go to the url(http://*****.*****.com/numbers.txt)
4. There is bunch of numbers under each other.
5. take those and print it in my html.
If you know shorter way doing this feel free to answer, I have done following, since i am beginner dont know how to continue from here :

```js
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", async function(event) {
  var response = await fetch("http://*****.*****.com/numbers.txt");
var arr = await response.txt();

function pressed() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ...;
}
```

```html
<h1>Numberss</h1>
  

  <input type="button" value="Press" onclick="pressed">
 
  <p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: `.txt()` is not a `Response` method. Other than fixing that, it looks like all you need to do is assign th result to the the element's text.

Comment: @CertainPerformance In URL there is bunch of numbers and its not json, i just want to print all these numbers in my html, thats it.

Comment: If you want just the text, then you should use the `.text()` method.

Comment: @CertainPerformance the URL contains bunch of numbers like this 27:4987, hundreds under each other, I want to print all the numbers from there in my html

Comment: Sure - regardless, you should use `.text()` if you want to retrieve text from a `Response` object.

Answer (score 0):

To get the returned value from the fetch you need to do the following:

```
var response;

await fetch("http://*****.*****.com/numbers.txt")
then( async (resp) => {
    // I dont know how the response will look like, 
    // but you might need to get a property, in which case you can do:
    // response = (await resp.json()).propertyWIthData
    response = await resp.json();
});
```

and then do whatever you need with the text from the response

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering, that 'response' is not compulsory, i just need all those numbers from url printed to my html, thats it.

Answer (score 0):

Without know the exact format of what's being returned from the API it's difficult to do much.  You also put an extremely low amount of effort into your question, with your demo not even working or even compiling.  You may not know how to do what you want, but you should at least know to close your functions and such, that just shows a disregard for our time.

I've fixed your demo but there is no way to help you without further information, or you could give us a valid url to work with (either the one you wish to work with or a similar one from https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/).

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", async function(event) {
  let mockData = [
    "a", "b", "C", "daddy"
  ];
  
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (mockData.reduce((total, current) => {
    return total + " - " + current;
  }, ""));
});


function pressed() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "...";
}
```

```html
<h1>Numberss</h1>
  

  <input type="button" value="Press" onclick="pressed()">
 
  <p id="demo"> Hi </p>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering, i made simple mistake there instead using 'function pressed()' i used 'function onclick()', my point is i just need all those numbers from url printed to my html, thats it.

Comment: You also don't close your addEventListener function but this is all beside the point. I'll update my answer to show one of the many ways this could be done.

Comment: the URL contains bunch of numbers like this 27:4987, hundreds under each other, I want to print all the numbers from there in my html

Comment: Just print them?  Put them in p tags?  Are you going to want it to update when you remove an item from the stored list when a button is clicked?  Is the list even stored or should it just be written out immediately?  Your question is extremely unclear and it sounds like you're asking me to do the work for you.  To be clear, I don't see how you don't have the tools given my answer to do what you wish to do.